# Clear div on button click(ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have div, where I append some data on button click. Here is code

```
$('#display').click(function () {
    $(".videolist").empty();
    var vacancyId = $("#vacancy").val();
    var model = {
        vacancyId: vacancyId
    };
    var today = new Date();
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Links", "Questions")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var question2 = data;

            for (var i = 0; i <= question2.length - 1; i++) {
                var videoHTML = '<div style="width:100%;overflow-y: scroll;background:white;height:60%;border-bottom:solid;border-color: #A9A9A9;">' + '<div style="float:left; width:50%;height:296px;border-right:solid;border-color: #A9A9A9;margin-bottom:10px;">' +
                    '<video  style="width:100%;height:290px; object-fit: contain;padding-right: 15px;padding-left:15px;" controls>';
                videoHTML += '<source src="' + document.location.origin + "/uploads/" + question2[i].Linkes + ".webm" + '" type="video/webm">';
                videoHTML += '</video>' + '</div>' + '<div style="float:right;width:48%;text-align:center;height:296px;padding-top:30px;">' + '<div style="font-size:20px">' + '<b>' + question2[i].FIO + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div style="font-size:20px">' + '<b>' + question2[i].City + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div style="font-size:20px">' + '<b>' + (yyyy - question2[i].Vozrast) + '</b>' + '</div>' + '<div class="qustion-div-two" style="height:160px;margin-top:20px; background:white;" >' +
                    '<div id="comments" style="width: 100%; height: 70%;">' + '</div>' +
                    '<div id="write_field" style="width:100%;height:30%;">' +
                    '<input type="text" style="width:99%; height:75%;margin-left:2px;margin-bottom:5px;" />' + '</div>' + '</div>' + '</div>';
                $(".videolist").append(videoHTML);

            }
        }
    });
});
```

When I select another vacancy I see previous generated divs.

I try to clear it via this `$(".videolist").empty();`, but it not works. Where is my mistake?

Thank's for help.

Comment: `empty()` should work fine. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: are you using IE? if so it can cache ajax requests. add cache: false as a parameter to your ajax call and see if that fixes it

Comment: All work's seems like it was cache. Thank's dude @Andrewbrough

Answer (score 0):

> Use this Code:
>
> `$(".videolist").html('');`

It Should work